# How to add indent after first line in every table name in list of tables?

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to add indent after first line in every table name in list of tables, like the images below. How to do that?

[image]

into this

[image]

This is my code :

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{book}
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, inner=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}% load as last package
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
linefill=\bfseries\TOCLineLeaderFill,
beforeskip=0pt,
entrynumberformat=\chapterprefixintoc,
dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter}

\newcommand*\chapterprefixintoc[1]
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~#1\enskip}

\begin{document}
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CONTENTS}
    \tableofcontents

    %=========TABLE======================
    \newpage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR TABEL}
    \setcounter{page}{15}
    \begin{singlespacing}
        \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
        \renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%
        \listoftables\end{singlespacing}
    \newpage
    \null\vfill
    %===========================================

    \chapter{PENDAHULUAN}
    contents...
    \section{Latar Belakang}
    contents...
    \subsection{ABCD}
    contents
    \subsection{EFGH}
    ...
    \section{Rumusan Masalah}
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    blablabla
    \section{Tujuan Penulisan}
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    blablabla..

    \chapter{DASAR TEORI}
    contents...
    \chapter{PEMBAHASAN}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \captionsetup{
            font=footnotesize,
            justification=raggedright,
            singlelinecheck=false
        }
        \caption{Naik dan turunnya nilai parameter $\beta,\alpha,\omega$ sebesar $10\%$, menaikkan dan menurunkan nilai $R_0$ sebesar $10\%$}\label{tabel3}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{No}&\multirow{2}{*}{Parameter} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Nilai $R_0$}\\\cline{3-4}
            &&$p+10\%$&$p-10\%$\\
            \hline
            1 & $\beta$ & $4.18539$ & $3.42441$\\
            \hline
            2 & $\alpha$ & $3.83536$ & $3.77342$\\
            \hline
            3 & $\omega$ & $3.99695$ & $3.59932$\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \captionsetup{
            font=normalsize,
            justification=raggedright,
            singlelinecheck=false
        }
        \caption{Naik dan turunnya nilai parameter $\phi,\rho$ sebesar $10\%$, menaikkan dan menurunkan nilai $R_0$ sebesar $10\%$}\label{tabel4}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{No}&\multirow{2}{*}{Parameter} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Nilai $R_0$}\\\cline{3-4}
            &&$p+10\%$&$p-10\%$\\
            \hline
            1 & $\phi$ & $3.58773$ & $4.05005$\\
            \hline
            2 & $\rho$ & $3.68281$ & $3.93536$\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \chapter{PENUTUP}
    contents...
    \chapter*{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
    contents
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With package `tocbasic` you can use `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` for `table` and `figure` to add the prefix and to set `numwidth` automatically using option `dynnumwidth`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, inner=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}% instead times
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}% load as last package

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  linefill=\bfseries\TOCLineLeaderFill,
  beforeskip=0pt,
  entrynumberformat=\useprefix{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}},
  dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  indent=0pt,
  entrynumberformat=\useprefix{\tablename},
  dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{table}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  indent=0pt,
  entrynumberformat=\useprefix{\figurename},
  dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{figure}

\newcommand*\useprefix[2]
  {#1~#2\enskip}

\begin{document}
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CONTENTS}
    \tableofcontents

    %=========TABLE======================
    \newpage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR TABEL}
    \setcounter{page}{15}
    \begin{singlespacing}
        \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
        \renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%
        \listoftables
    \end{singlespacing}
    \newpage
    \null\vfill
    %===========================================

    \chapter{PENDAHULUAN}
    contents...
    \section{Latar Belakang}
    contents...
    \subsection{ABCD}
    contents
    \subsection{EFGH}
    ...
    \section{Rumusan Masalah}
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    blablabla
    \section{Tujuan Penulisan}
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    blablabla..

    \chapter{DASAR TEORI}
    contents...
    \chapter{PEMBAHASAN}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \captionsetup{
            font=footnotesize,
            justification=raggedright,
            singlelinecheck=false
        }
        \caption{Naik dan turunnya nilai parameter $\beta,\alpha,\omega$ sebesar $10\%$, menaikkan dan menurunkan nilai $R_0$ sebesar $10\%$}\label{tabel3}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{No}&\multirow{2}{*}{Parameter} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Nilai $R_0$}\\\cline{3-4}
            &&$p+10\%$&$p-10\%$\\
            \hline
            1 & $\beta$ & $4.18539$ & $3.42441$\\
            \hline
            2 & $\alpha$ & $3.83536$ & $3.77342$\\
            \hline
            3 & $\omega$ & $3.99695$ & $3.59932$\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \captionsetup{
            font=normalsize,
            justification=raggedright,
            singlelinecheck=false
        }
        \caption{Naik dan turunnya nilai parameter $\phi,\rho$ sebesar $10\%$, menaikkan dan menurunkan nilai $R_0$ sebesar $10\%$}\label{tabel4}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{No}&\multirow{2}{*}{Parameter} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Nilai $R_0$}\\\cline{3-4}
            &&$p+10\%$&$p-10\%$\\
            \hline
            1 & $\phi$ & $3.58773$ & $4.05005$\\
            \hline
            2 & $\rho$ & $3.68281$ & $3.93536$\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \chapter{PENUTUP}
    contents...
    \chapter*{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
    contents
\end{document}
```

Note that I have changed `entrynumberformat` for chapter to use the same command `\withprefix` as for `figure` and `table`.

Run three times to get

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @esdd . The code is work.